# How to communicate between Vue 3 composables?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Vue docs describe how composables can be used for code organization by composing the app of small composition functions.

[Extracting Composables for Code Organization](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#extracting-composables-for-code-organization)

> "You can think of these extracted composables as component-scoped services that can talk to one another."

But how do you communicate between these composables? How do I change a variable (ref) that is inside another composable. I am trying to build this app where I have 2 composables (users and statistics). And I need to change the `selectedUser` from inside the `loadStatistics` method. But I don't have access to the `selectedUser` from my `Statistics` composable. What is the best practice to do this?

**ShowStatistics.vue**

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedUser">
    <option v-for="user in users" :value="selectedUser">
      {{ user }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <button @click="loadStatistics">
    Load Statistics
  </button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    const { users, selectedUser } = useUsers()
    const { loadStatistics } = useStatistics()
</script>
```

**useUsers.ts**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

export function useUsers() {
    const users = ref([])
    const selectedUser = ref({})

    users.value = UsersApi.getUsers()

    return { users, selectedUser }
}
```

**useStatistics.ts**

```
export function useStatistics() {
    const loadStatistics = () => {
        window.store.statistics = StatisticsApi.loadStatistics()
        
        selectedUser = window.store.statistics.user
           // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR: selectedUser is not defined
    }

    return { loadStatistics }
}
```

Comment: From the use "store.statistics.user" it looks like you use local state where global state is expected

Comment: @EstusFlask it is `window.store` but that isn't the issue.

Comment: Looks like the use of global variables without a reason. Any way, you either pass `users` ref to useStatistics through args if it's local state, or keep it global state and use in both composables - either Pinia or your own, e.g. https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `selectedUser` ref from `useUsers()` to `useStatistics()` as an argument:

**ShowStatistics.vue:**

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
    const { users, selectedUser } = useUsers()
    const { loadStatistics } = useStatistics(selectedUser)
</script>
```

**useStatistics.ts:**

```
                                   
export function useStatistics(selectedUser) {
    const loadStatistics = () => {
        window.store.statistics = StatisticsApi.loadStatistics()
                 
        if (selectedUser) {
            selectedUser.value = window.store.statistics.user
        }
    }

    return { loadStatistics }
}
```

Comment: Now you have coupled the composables together defeating the exact purpose that the composables were created for. It feels a lot like a code smell.

Comment: Passing refs between composables is completely normal. I don't know why you think that defeats the purpose of compsables.

Comment: Yes, passing refs between composables is alright but changing a ref that belongs to another composables creates tight coupling.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging around and finding no example of how to do this in the official docs I will also post the answer that I found which is to return a derived state that I can later watch from inside the `useStatistics` composable. If anyone has a better idea, please do share but until then, this is the best solution I have found so far.

This solution also solves the tight coupling issue in case you wanted to change the `selectedUser` directly from inside the `useStatistics` composable (which defeats the purpose that the composables were created for).

```
export function useStatistics(selectedUser) {
    const selectedUserStatistics = ref(selectedUser)

    const loadStatistics = () => {
        window.store.statistics = StatisticsApi.loadStatistics()

        selectedUserStatistics.value = window.store.statistics.user
    }

    return { loadStatistics, selectedUserStatistics }
}
```